# Angular2 don't redirect to the page, change the URL but don't load the page

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm working with Angular2 and the routes, so, when I do click in a link the URL change but the body doesn't
this are my routes

```
import { Routes} from '@angular/router';
//Import components
import { NewComponent } from './new/new.component';
import { ShowComponent } from './show/show.component';
import { FunnelsComponent } from './funnels.component';

export const FUNNELS_ROUTES: Routes = [
{   path: 'newfunnel',
    component: NewComponent
},
{   path: 'showfunnel',
    component: ShowComponent
},
{
  path:'funnels',
  component: FunnelsComponent
},
{path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'funnels'}
];
```

and I use it like that

```
<a [routerLink]="['showfunnel']">
   <img src="assets/img/ic-vistaprevia.png" class="vista">
</a>
----------------------------------------------------
<a [routerLink]="['newfunnel']">New Funnel</a>
```

[this is my directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27IA2.png)

so, someone can help me to find my error?

Comment: did you add router-outlet?

Comment: you forget {path:'funnels', component:FunnelsComponent} -else Angular don't know how component show

Comment: @Chellappan Yes, I added it

Comment: @Eliseo these routes are children of funnels

Comment: {path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'funnels'} there is no `funnels` path

Comment: Why is your routerlink represented by an array with a string inside?  I'm not sure why you're doing that.  `[routerLink]="['showfunnel']` seems like it should be `[routerLink]="/showfunnel"`

Comment: try this. ```export const FUNNELS_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'funnels',
        component: FunnelsComponent,
        children: [
            {   path: 'newfunnel',
            component: NewComponent
            },
            {   path: 'showfunnel',
            component: ShowComponent
            },
            {path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'funnels' }
        ]
    }
];
```. And put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside your `FunnelsComponent`

Answer (score 0):

> Check this out this might help

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { NewComponent } from './new/new.component';
    import { ShowComponent } from './show/show.component';
    import { FunnelsComponent } from './funnels.component';



    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'funnels', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'newfunnel', component: NewComponent},
      { path: 'showfunnel', component: ShowComponent },
      { path: 'funnels', component: FunnelsComponent }

    ];



    @NgModule({
      imports:[
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
      ],
      exports: [ RouterModule ]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { // export class

    }
```

> HTML

```
<a routerLink="/showfunnel">
   <img src="assets/img/ic-vistaprevia.png" class="vista">
</a>
<a routerLink="/newfunnel">New Funnel</a>
```

Comment: when clicking, it redirects me to the index, closes session and shows me the landing